# Beginner at web scraping with Python. Does this website have a protection against scraping?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to do an automated daily web scrape of https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/agricultural/dairy/cash-settled-butter_quotes_globex.html
but am only getting empty lists as results. I think there may be some kind of protection on the site that is keeping it from being scraped.

I have used some tutorials to try to scrape the site using both BeautifulSoup4 and XPath, but both methods leave me with empty lists. I did get a 403 Forbidden error at one point, but found a workaround using "hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}" (whatever that means). I am new to web scraping, so I am not sure.

BeautifulSoup4 version gets results, but no actual data that I am looking for.

```
url = "https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/agricultural/dairy/cash-settled-butter_quotes_globex.html"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = Request(url,headers=hdr)
page = urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
print(soup.prettify())
```

Xpath version seems to connect, but does not deliver data.

```
from lxml import html
import requests
url = "https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/agricultural/dairy/cash-settled-butter_quotes_globex.html"
response = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(response.content)
data = tree.xpath('//*[@id="quotesFuturesProductTable1"]/tbody/tr[1]/th/span')
data
```

I want to pull the name, month, and prior settle. Then eventually figure out how to make it pull the data automatically daily.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you see on the webpage is loaded dynamically through Javascript. BeautifulSoup won't help you here, because it doesn't execute Javascript.

You can use `selenium` for example. Or parsing the data manually with `re` and `json` modules. This code will load data in json format and prints it to the screen:

```
import re
import json
import requests

url = 'https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/agricultural/dairy/cash-settled-butter_quotes_globex.html'

data_url = 'https://www.cmegroup.com' + re.findall(r'component\.url = "(.*?)"', requests.get(url).text)[0]

json_data = requests.get(data_url).json()

print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```
{
    "quoteDelayed": true,
    "quoteDelay": "10 minutes",
    "tradeDate": "14 Aug 2019",
    "quotes": [
        {
            "last": "235.850",
            "change": "+0.800",
            "priorSettle": "235.050",
            "open": "235.050",
            "close": "-",
            "high": "235.850",
            "low": "235.050",
            "highLimit": "241.725",
            "lowLimit": "231.725",
            "volume": "2",
            "mdKey": "CBQ9-XCME-G",
            "quoteCode": "CBQ9",
            "escapedQuoteCode": "CBQ9",
            "code": "CBQ9",
            "updated": "11:27:33 CT<br /> 14 Aug 2019",
            "percentageChange": "+0.34%",
            "expirationMonth": "AUG 2019",
            "expirationCode": "Q9",
            "expirationDate": "20190801",
            "productName": "Cash-settled Butter Futures",
            "productCode": "CB",
            "uri": "/trading/agricultural/dairy/cash-settled-butter.html",
            "productId": 26,
            "exchangeCode": "XCME",
            "optionUri": "/trading/agricultural/dairy/cash-settled-butter_quotes_options.html",
            "hasOption": true,
            "lastTradeDate": {
                "timestamp": 1567573200000,
                "dateOnlyLongFormat": "04 Sep 2019",
                "default24": "09/04/2019, 00:00:00 CDT",
                "default12": "09/04/2019, 12:00:00 AM CDT",
                "verbose": "September 04, 2019 12:00:00 AM CDT"
            },
            "priceChart": {
                "enabled": true,
                "code": "CB",
                "monthYear": "Q9",
                "venue": 1,
                "title": "AUG_2019_Cash-settled_Butter_",
                "year": 2019
            },
            "netChangeStatus": "statusOK",
            "highLowLimits": "241.725 / 231.725"
        },

...and so on.
```